# How to switch to another domain and get-aduser

Tags: powershell, active-directory, cross-domain

I am on a server under the DomainA. I can use `Get-ADUser` and it's working fine.

Now there is a trust built between DomainA and DomainB. I would like to switch to DomainB and get all the users that's in `OU=New Users, DC=DomainB, DC=com`.

I tried these but I get an error.

```
$FetchDomainB = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=New Users, DC=DomainB, DC=com"
```

This asks me for Filter and i put in emailadress then it throws an error saying "Supplied distinguished name below to dc=DomainA,dc=net"

Same error is thrown for following code as well.

```
PS C:\> $test = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "dc=DomainB,dc=com" -filter {EmailAddress -like "*Smith_Karla*"} -Properties EmailAddress
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try specifying a DC in DomainB using the `-Server` property. Ex:

```
Get-ADUser -Server "dc01.DomainB.local" -Filter {EmailAddress -like "*Smith_Karla*"} -Properties EmailAddress
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked. I had to get the domain info using get-addomain Domain.B first to get the domain server the update the code and worked like a charm. Thanks Frode

Comment: any idea why it only giving few elements not the entire details. it gives enabled, givenname, name, objectclass, objectguid, sameaccoutnname, sid, surename and userprincalpalname. I need all the fields including OU

Comment: @Axiom it will only provide the properties you request. If you need something outside of that list you need to use `-Properties`. DistinguishedName kind of has this information though already. More ideas [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/830ff383-9057-45d8-ae10-5e567efd36f8/how-to-get-parent-container-path-of-the-ad-user-object)

Comment: If you need all properties/atributes, use `-Properties *`. If you only need a few, then you could specify them like @Matt suggested

Answer (score 27):

I just want to add that if you don't inheritently know the name of a domain controller, you can get the closest one, pass it's hostname to the `-Server` argument.

```
$dc = Get-ADDomainController -DomainName example.com -Discover -NextClosestSite

Get-ADUser -Server $dc.HostName[0] `
    -Filter { EmailAddress -Like "*Smith_Karla*" } `
    -Properties EmailAddress
```

Answer (score 5):

```
get-aduser -Server "servername" -Identity %username% -Properties *

get-aduser -Server "testdomain.test.net" -Identity testuser -Properties *
```

These work when you have the username. Also less to type than using the `-filter` property.

EDIT: Formatting.

Comment: Drawbacks to solution:

Line #1:  requires that you know the name of the nearest domain controller (meaning over time it may break as new DC's are added and old ones taken away), or

Line 2:  Requires that you ignore the nearest DC and just pick any DC in the other domain at random based on DNS response.
If these don't present a problem, then either solution will work.

Answer (score 1):

best solution TNX to Drew Chapin and all of you too:

I just want to add that if you don't inheritently know the name of a domain controller, you can get the closest one, pass it's hostname to the -Server argument.

```
$dc = Get-ADDomainController -DomainName example.com -Discover -NextClosestSite

Get-ADUser -Server $dc.HostName[0] `
    -Filter { EmailAddress -Like "*Smith_Karla*" } `
    -Properties EmailAddress
```

my script:

```
$dc = Get-ADDomainController -DomainName example.com -Discover -NextClosestSite
 Get-ADUser -Server $dc.HostName[0] ` -Filter { EmailAddress -Like "*Smith_Karla*" } `  -Properties EmailAddress | Export-CSV "C:\Scripts\Email.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in multiple domains one after another using below script:

Here, first we check whether user is present in a domain and if so, we get the email address. Else we check in the subsequent domain.

```
$users = Get-Content D:\UserBase\users.txt
 foreach($user in $users)
 {
     if([bool] (Get-ADUser -Filter { SamAccountName -eq $user } -Server DomainA.com))
     {
        Get-ADUser -Filter { SamAccountName -eq $user } -Server DomainA.com -Properties Mail |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Mail  | Out-file D:\UserBase\emails.txt -Append
     } 
     elseif([bool] (Get-ADUser -Filter { SamAccountName -eq $user } -Server DomainB.com))
     {
      Get-ADUser -Filter { SamAccountName -eq $user } -Server DomainB.com -Properties Mail |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Mail  | Out-file D:\UserBase\emails.txt -Append
     }
```

Also, you can get the list of domains in the organization using below script:

```
  $ForestObj = Get-ADForest -Server $env:USERDOMAIN
foreach($Domain in $ForestObj.Domains) {
    Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $Domain | select Domain,HostName,Site
    }
```